# PhoneGap Mobile Rails Authentication (devise? authentication from scratch?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cordova, devise

I have a PhoneGap app with a Rails backend. I'm trying to figure out what the best way is to authenticate a user from the mobile app using json.

I am using devise currently, *but I don't have to use that*. What would be the most simple way to modify devise to work with a mobile app in Phonegap?

I know there are quite a few posts on this... but, some of them are outdated or seem like very complex hacks. Hoping there may be more up to date info from some tried and tested projects, or tutorials.

One post I found also suggests using jsonp, but it also seemed like a pretty complex hack. You can find it here: http://vimeo.com/18763953

I'm also wondering if I would just be better off starting out with authentication from scratch, as laid out in this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should override devise's [sessions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb) and [registrations](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) controller. I'll only show you how to override the sessions controller:

First, go to your User model and add the Token Authenticatable module. Something like this:

```
devise :token_authenticatable

before_save :ensure_authentication_token
```

Then edit your devise.rb file to configure that module:

```
# You can skip storage for :http_auth and :token_auth by adding those symbols to the array below.
config.skip_session_storage = [:token_auth]

# Defines name of the authentication token params key
config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token
```

Now edit your routes and point to your new controllers:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations', :sessions => 'sessions' }
```

And then create your controller like this:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        super
      }
      format.json {
        build_resource
        user = User.find_for_database_authentication(:email => params[:user][:email])
        return invalid_login_attempt unless resource

        if user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
          render :json => { :auth_token => user.authentication_token }, success: true, status: :created
        else
          invalid_login_attempt
        end
      }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        super
      }
      format.json {
        user = User.find_by_authentication_token(params[:auth_token])
        if user
          user.reset_authentication_token!
          render :json => { :message => 'Session deleted.' }, :success => true, :status => 204
        else
          render :json => { :message => 'Invalid token.' }, :status => 404
        end
      }
    end
  end

  protected
  def invalid_login_attempt
    warden.custom_failure!
    render json: { success: false, message: 'Error with your login or password' }, status: 401
  end
end
```

Devise [has a page about this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example), but it only points to some already outdated guides. But maybe it will help you.

Comment: +1 thanks for this. do you know much about storing the session on the mobile end? i hear that phonegap doesn't have cookies, so would that mean i'd have to use localStorage to store the cookie and then somehow post that with each request?

Comment: btw @Ashitaka, you're right, those docs are a bit outdated. I'm really surprised this kind of setup isn't documented more since mobile apps and rails seems to be the trend these days.

Comment: Just search for local storage, it's super easy. In your Phonegap app, when logging in, make an ajax call to the session url (you can find it using `rake routes`) and then store the token with this: `localStorage.setItem('auth_token', authentication_token);`. You can then retrieve it with `localStorage.getItem('auth_token')`.

Comment: A month ago I and a couple friends made a college project using Devise and Phonegap. You can have a look but take it with a grain of salt. It was our first time using Phonegap so it's not a pretty app but hey, we got the job done. Here is **[the server](https://github.com/GuilhermeSimoes/rails_alacarte_server/blob/master/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb#L1)** and here is **[the client](https://github.com/Penetra/alacarte_android_client/blob/master/assets/www/login.html#L50)**. Hope it helps!

Comment: hey @Ashitaka thanks a lot! i will take a look and get back at you :)