# how to use xml for device authentication sample

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, blackberry, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am currently working on a mobile application where people need to authenticate from the mobile app using xml for the mobile app and devise on the server side.

I have never used xml before and and am just trying in out for the first time so i will like know were i can get an xml sample of devise authentication or any code sample as the answer using username and password with a custom create session action with xml response for successful and failure login will be great. thank You.

Comment: What platform is your mobile app for?

Comment: Take a look at **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623562/phonegap-mobile-rails-authentication-devise-authentication-from-scratch/13632264)**. It's about authenticating with Devise using json but you should be able to adapt it easily to be able to authenticate using xml.