# ActiveAdmin with Devise, does not return the authentication_token when login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin app that uses the User model (instead of the default AdminUser one). User has a role (blank or admin)

app/model/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :token_authenticatable

      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role

      has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
      has_many :items, :through => :groups

      before_save :ensure_authentication_token

      def is_admin?
        @role.eql?("admin") ? true : false
      end
end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
Lao::Application.routes.draw do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
end
```

In DeviseCreateUser migration, I have added:

```
## Token authenticatable
t.string :authentication_token
```

If I log through the following HTTP POST request:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -XPOST http://localhost:3000/admin/login.json -d '{"user" : {"email" : "user@email.com", "password" : "password"}}'
```

I do not get the authentication token:

```
=> {"created_at":"2013-04-17T17:11:38Z","email":"user@email.com","id":2,"role":null,"updated_at":"2013-04-17T17:53:37Z"}
```

How can I get the authentication token in the response ? I cannot find out why the "created_at", "email", "id", "role" and "updated_at" field are the one that are sent out. How can this list be changed ?

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13632264/1908371) for something quite in depth. You need to override ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#create with something that returns the json you want.

The easiest(and not ideal) way to do that is to just add

```
class ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    #your session creation code
  end
  def destroy
    #your session destruction code
  end                 
end
```

At the very bottom of config/active_admin.rb, this replaces AA's session creation/destruction methods with yours.

For simpler replacement code see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/danielgatis/5666941) and the last comment.